# How to highlight files that were also modified in commits after the common ancestor during a git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, githooks, gitkraken

While doing a `rebase`, git is doing its "magic" by doing an auto-merge.

Even if there is no conflict, I would like to be warned on the files that were also modified in the other branch.

In another words, if I am working on a file, I would like to know if others of my team had worked on the same file in the meantime. It could reveal a lack of communication while working on the project.
Therefore, I would like a kind of report or a warning.

I would say that the worst case scenario is when there is no conflict because git is rebasing silently my modifications on files that require my attention.

I do not know if it is possible to do it with `pre-rebase hook` but I would like the solution to be integrated with git client like `Gitkraken`.

On some git client, I could see the list of files for '`AHEAD`' and '`BEHIND`', I would like the intersection of both.

I am pretty sure that I am not the first one asking that question but I could not find any answer on this specific topic.

I hope I was clear enough, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know how to check the file list with a script, I don't know if GitKraken has a way to execute scripts and display their output integrated to its GUI.

---

If you are running `git rebase target`, git will replay all commmits since the *merge base* between your current commit and target onto target.

Here are the base commands that will compute the merge base, and list modified files on either side :

```
base=$(git merge-base HEAD target)

# modified on the target branch :
git diff --name-only $base target
# modified on your current branch :
git diff --name-only $base HEAD
```

You can use grep to find files modified on both sides :

```
base=$(git merge-base HEAD target)

git diff --name-only $base target | grep -f <(git diff --name-only $base HEAD)
```